# H12 errors in the European region

Tags: heroku

I moved my app over to the European region and I have the feeling I'm having more H12 timeout errors than I used to have when in the US.
Am I the only one experiencing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I work at Heroku)

No, You're not alone.  We've had a few reports of this and are actively investigating the issue.  If you're having problems, please raise a support ticket and we will see what we can do to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

You are not alone. We are experiencing the same thing from time to time. The major problem is that when a dyno starts to time out, it does not recover. The only solution I have found so far is to restart the app. Scaling does not help either, since the stuck dynos will continue to get requests.

We have reported this to Heroku, but it does not seem like Heroku has acknowledged that they have this problem in the EU region. Twice today we have had to restart the app due to H12, and it is quite annoying.

Previously Heroku support suggested we use the "rack timeout" gem, so that the app it self times out the request before Heroku does it. It does not seem to fix the problem, so my assumption is that the problem is related to Herokus own infrastructure.

Comment: I actually got an acknowledgement from Heroku that more people reported these issues and that somebody is looking into it. I also get the H12's when the site is idle, no users at all. It doesn't seem to be the same H12 that you get in the US when your requests are over the 30 secs.